# Elementary.io website is down in Egypt

Tags: elementary-website

I'm having trouble visiting the website of elementary OS from Alexandria, Egypt

is anyone else facing the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

it's up... at least here
although have no idea why it's in Turkish